# Loading drawable into Fragment

Tags: java, android

I've got a LinearLayout which I want to set a drawable background

```
fragments.add(new FragmentTypeC().newInstance(getString(R.string.Historie6_header), R.drawable.london_old_stock_exchange));
```

But it says that in this line a NULLPointerException is thrown and that the resource can't be found. This is my oncreateview:

```
     View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_type_c, container, false);

    webViewHeader = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.header_type_c);
    imageLayout = (LinearLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.layout_type_c);

    webViewHeader.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", loadHTLMContentHeader(header), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8", null);
    webViewHeader.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

    imageLayout.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), picId, null));



    return root;
}
```

Anybody got an idea how i fix it?

Comment: In which function you are trying to set backgroundDrawable like in OnCreate or what? i think imageLayout might have not been initialized?

Comment: @AdnanAmjad I've edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
imageLayout.setBackgroundResource(picId);
```